# What are some good Kubernetes training courses?

Tags: kubernetes, learning

I'm looking for Kubernetes training online or in person. What are some good training courses to take?

Comment: I would expect in this question to do a basic google search and explain why none of the links in the first 3 pages did not work for you. That would get people some idea how to focus the answers.

Answer (score 1):

To understand kubernetes internal, it's good to have good understanding of containers, docker, etc.

Here, is the list of useful docker and kubernetes resources:

1) Play with Docker Classroom https://training.play-with-docker.com/

2) Docker Interactive Tutorials https://www.katacoda.com/

3) Play with Docker (PWD) https://labs.play-with-docker.com/
    Play with Kubernetes(PWK) https://labs.play-with-k8s.com/

4) [Introduction to Kubernetes course on edX](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-kubernetes) also his company, [CloudYuga](https://cloudyuga.guru/) is a certified Kubernetes service provider and training partner

5) Blog by Docker Captain, https://collabnix.com/
    Also, search kubenetes blogs on Medium which are very useful.

6) Kubernetes The Hard Way [github](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way) repo by Kelsey hightower updated with latest kubernetes 1.12.0 version.

Hope this helps.